# Changing acl permissions of user1 home directory so nongroup member can access it while group members cannot

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, acl

I have several users in several different groups.  So...

```
sudo su

>$ ls -l /home/
drwxr-x---   5 root   group1         4096 Mar 18 12:44 group1
drwxr-x---   6 root   group2         4096 Feb  9 13:58 group2

>$ ls -l /home/group1
drwx------ 6 user1 group1 4096 Mar 23 15:57 user1
drwx------ 6 user2 group1 4096 Mar 23 12:19 user2
```

Now user3 is a member of group2.  I want user3 to be able to read and execute user1's home directory but I don't want to permit user2 (who is in the same group as user1) to have any permissions to user1's home directory.

If I try using acl's.

```
>$ getfacl /home/group1/user1
# file: user1/
# owner: user1
# group: group1
user::rwx
group::---
other::---

>$ setfacl -m u:user3:rx /home/group1/user1/
>$ getfacl /home/group1/user1
# file: user1/
# owner: user1
# group: group1
user::rwx
user:user3:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---

>$ ls -l /home/group1
drwxr-x---+ 11 user1 group1 4096 Mar 22 14:57 user1
drwx------   6 user2 group1 4096 Mar 23 12:19 user2
```

Since I changed the acl's, the group permissions of user1's home directory *also* changed.  Now user2 can read and execute in user1's home directory.  The man page for setfacl is a bit sparse.

QUESTION : is there a way to give user3 (who's in group2) permission to user1's home directory without automatically giving user2 permission?

I would like to use acl's for this.

Comment: Did you tried to _create a new `group_N` Create a new user `UserNew`. Do member `UserNew` `user1` and `user3` of the `group_N`. Change the ownership of the home of user1 to `UserNew` and `group_N`. Allo._w read write execute to user and group_? It should work but I did not suggest you to do for the home. Better to try in a subdir of the home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you really check that user2 can read and execute in user1's home directory?

Hi shouldn't. 
Everything is done with acl's you set with setfacl.

Comment: You are correct.  user2 cannot read user1's home directory.  I guess I was misled by the permissions printed by ls -l.  Why does it show the group permissions as being rx?